# how to watch the eth address with infura

Tags: web3js, ether, infura

our project now uses scheduled task to query the eth address with infura API to get its balance every 10 seconds but as the number of addresses keep increasing, the efficiency is very bad.

Is there any way to subscribe to the address so we will get notified whenever there is any change in the balance. Or do we have to set up our own node?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to do it Infura. I know you can set up a Moralis Stream to get a webhook every time the balance of a specific set of addresses changes, that would work both for native balance like ETH or for tokens/NFTs.

You can create a stream either in the UI or through the SDK/API (seen below). You do one call to [create the stream](https://docs.moralis.io/streams-api/evm/reference/create-stream) with the config you want, and then an additional call every time you want to [attach new addresses](https://docs.moralis.io/streams-api/evm/reference/add-address-to-stream) to the same stream.

The `includeNativeTxs` flag indicates that you configure the stream to listen to native transactions only, which affects the native balance of the address.

Every time you get one of these webhooks, you can then call to check the native balance of that address. Either through Moralis [Balance API](https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/evm/wallet-api/how-to-get-the-balance-of-a-wallet) or Infura.

If you're on a paid moralis plan you can also use the [getNativeBalances](https://docs.moralis.io/streams-api/evm/get-native-balances) option in your stream which automatically will fetch the native balance and include it in every webhook.

Here is a good get started [guide](https://docs.moralis.io/streams-api/evm/using-node-js-sdk) too.

```
const options = {
    webhookUrl: "<https://YOUR_WEBHOOK_URL>",
    description: "api-demo",
    tag: "api-demo",
    demo: "true",
    chainIds: ["0x1"], //Support for multiple chains 
    includeNativeTxs: true 
};

const stream = await Moralis.Streams.add(options);

const { id } = stream.toJSON(); // { id: 'YOUR_STREAM_ID', ...stream }

// Attach the contract address to the stream
await Moralis.Streams.addAddress({
  id,
  address: ["<WALLET_ADDRESS_1>", "<WALLET_ADDRESS_2>"], // Add as many addresses as you want
});
```

Full disclosure, I work at Moralis.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is receiving events about balance changing for set of addresses. There is no native way to do this with current implementations of clients(nodes), at least what I know.

Whereas you have to request balances, running own node will delay in issue with performance.

I would modify client to track addresses.

Comment: can you share some code how to receive events about balance changing for set of addresses?